# Detect Airplane Mode on iOS in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, airplane-mode

When accessing Safari or Email on the iPhone (at least 7.1) if airplane mode is on, an alert pops up that says;

> Turn Off Airplane Mode or Use Wi-Fi to Access Data.

The two choices are Settings which takes you to Settings or OK which just cancels the alert.

I would like to have something similar in my app so people know they can't access the server.

However, the answers I have read on Stack Overflow suggest there is no way for 3rdparty apps to check if airplane mode is enabled.  Note, this is not the same as just checking if Internet is enabled because it takes user directly to Settings screen if airplane mode is the issue.

How to implement this functionality in iPhone?

Comment: There is no public API for that. There are SO threads that suggest private APIs but thats something you wouldn't be able to use in App Store app anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect airplane mode on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804398/detect-airplane-mode-on-ios) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067713/how-can-i-know-airplane-mode-on-or-off-in-ios)